# input type check boxes are not working with lable tag

Tags: html

Here is the HTML for 4 checkboxes -  2 are working and the other two (Female and Menu) are not working. I do not know how to make them work.

```
<h1>testing Checkbox</h1>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id">
<label for="checkbox_id">Text</label>


<input type="checkbox" id="male">
<label for="male">Male</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="fe_male">
<lable for="fe_male">Fe Male</lable>

<lable><input type="checkbox"> MENU</lable>
```

please help me Thanks

Comment: lable is not the same as label, please check your code at least once before posting please..

Comment: ok i will be care full

Answer (score 1):

`<lable>` is not a valid tag. You have made a typo, it should be `<label>`.